# call php script in another php file

Tags: php

i have multiple php files. Script(handler.php) is executed by cron job every xy minutes. Although in another file (index.php) i want to call handler.php after user clicks on button, so the update will apply immediately and i dont have to wait for crob job execute, which takes xy minutes.

My question is - how can i call/execute script handler.php after i make successful sql update in code below?

Here is code sample from index.php, where i want to call handler.php.

```
if($_REQUEST['btn_submit']=="Button1")
            {
                if (is_numeric($int_1) && is_numeric($int_2))  {
                     if ($int_1 <= $int_2){
                        $sql_update_1 = "UPDATE events SET interval_from = $int_1, interval_to = $int_2, updated_at = now() WHERE name = 'Temperature'";
                        if($conn->query($sql_update_1) === TRUE){
                           // CALL HERE handler.php 
                            echo "Records added successfully.";
                        } else{
                            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                        }
                     }

                     else {
                        echo "Wrong input ";
                     }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `require_once('handler.php')` to include the script and run it.

Comment: If you are running with index.php, where you want to call handler.php.

Please include that code file inside where you want. for that, you can use include/include_once or require_once.